# Blue Pelican Java project "Masking Telemetry Data"; compiling but not running?

Tags: java, debugging, telemetry

I've been trying this project in Blue Pelican Java for over an hour, and I'm not quite sure why it's not working. Basically what I have to do is turn a regular number into a binary number, and, assuming that 1 means the switch is open and 0 means it's closed, go through each digit in the binary number and print whether it's open or closed. They stated how they want me to do this:

> "Suppose we wish to look at the third bit from the left. Use a mask as
>   illustrated below to bitwise AND with the original number in order to
>   look only at the third bit. 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1bin = 177dec 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
>   0bin = 32dec (this is the mask)
>
> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0bin = 32dec = (177 & 32)
>
> Notice this scheme of bitwise AND-ing a mask value of 32 (25, since
>   the third bit position from the left has a positional value of 25)
>   yields a value in the third bit position exactly equal to the third
>   bit position of the original number. All other bit positions are
>   guaranteed to be 0’s. Thus, this result of bitwise AND-ing can be
>   tested to see if its entire value is 0. If it’s greater than 0, this
>   means that the bit in the tested position was a 1."

At this point I am just testing the first number, 22, in the Switches.in folder, instead of importing the entire folder just yet, for the code. My code compiles, it begins to start printing what I want but suddenly cuts and goes to an error message that looks like this:

```
Switch sw57is "off
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:32)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int j=22;
    String jj=Integer.toBinaryString(j);
    StringTokenizer sc=new StringTokenizer(jj,"");
    int l=(sc.countTokens());


    int a[]=new int[l];
    int xx=0;
    for(int x=l; x>-1; x--)
    {
        xx=xx++;
        double p=(Math.pow(2,xx));
        int pp=(int)p;
        int n=((j)&(pp));
        String nn=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        StringTokenizer nnn=new StringTokenizer(nn);
        int po=(nnn.countTokens());
        int sum=0;

        System.out.println(nnn);

        for(int xxx=-1; xxx<po; xxx++)
        {
            sum=sum+(Integer.parseInt(nnn.nextToken()));


        if(sum>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Switch sw"+(x+56)+"is \"on");
        }
        else if(sum==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Switch sw"+(x+56)+"is \"off");
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, and sorry for the lengthy post!

Comment: So what is the expected complete output for your test case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, starting from `-1` you will exceed the number of tokens available:

```
for (int xxx = -1; xxx < po; xxx++) {
```

where

```
po = nnn.countTokens()
```

...so, to correct, use:

```
for (int xxx = 0; xxx < po; xxx++) {
```

Furthermore, as xxx isn't used anywhere else, you could simply use:

```
while (nnn.hasMoreTokens()) {
   sum = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with `sum=sum+(Integer.parseInt(nnn.nextToken()));`. Please see

1. [java StringTokenizer - can nextToken return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773192/java-stringtokenizer-can-nexttoken-return-null)
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken

I think following code fixes the issue (I have added a few println for debug info):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int j=22;
    String jj=Integer.toBinaryString(j);
    StringTokenizer sc=new StringTokenizer(jj,"");
    int l=(sc.countTokens());


    int a[]=new int[l];
    int xx=0;
    for(int x=l; x>-1; x--)
    {
        xx=xx++;
        double p=(Math.pow(2,xx));
        int pp=(int)p;
        int n=((j)&(pp));
        String nn=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        StringTokenizer nnn=new StringTokenizer(nn);
        String nToken;
        int po=(nnn.countTokens());
        int sum=0;
        System.out.println("x = "+ x);
        System.out.println("po = "+ po);

        System.out.println(nnn);

        for(int xxx=0; xxx<po; xxx++)
        {
            System.out.println("xxx = "+ xxx);
            sum=sum+(Integer.parseInt(nnn.nextToken()));


        if(sum>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Switch sw"+(x+56)+"is \"on");
        }
        else if(sum==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Switch sw"+(x+56)+"is \"off");
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a stated file in which you are getting your data from. If you would like your program to work you might consider putting a file from which you get your data.